# Deny other users to edit someone else's cards

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an update page where users can edit their business cards' informations, like phone, address..
The problem is, I'm getting their cards id in this way:

```
 <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-succes" role="button">Edit</a>
```

so they can see their card id in the search bar and if they just simply change the id, they can edit anyone's card informations. I wanted to check if the user's id equals to his card userid - (this is a foreign key in the database) and if not, redirect him to the index page. The problem is, I'm still allowed to edit anyone's card because the userid doesn't change.

my update code:

```
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'reg');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("HIBA: Nem sikerült csatlakozni. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$id = $_GET['id'];

var_dump($_SESSION);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $job = $_POST['job'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];

    if( $_SESSION['id'] != $userid){
      header("Location: index.php");
     }





    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE cards SET name=?, phone=?, phone2=?, email=?, zipcode=?, address=?, job=?, description=?, visibility=?, confirmed=?  WHERE id = ?');

    if (
        $stmt &&
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssisssii', $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $visibility, $confirmed) &&
        $stmt -> execute()
        ) {
            echo 'Updated';
    } else {
        echo $mysqli -> error;
    }
} 


$getstmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id= ?");

if ($getstmt and
    $getstmt->bind_param('i', $id) and
    $getstmt->execute() and
    $result = $getstmt->get_result() and
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    ) {

    $name = $row['name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $phone2 = $row['phone2'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $job = $row['job'];
    $description = $row['description'];
```

my database: (users)

```
id-   username-   password-  created-     admin-
----------------------------------------------
1       John        112      2020-12-23   2435
```

cards:

```
id-   name-   phone-  phone2-  email-  zipcode-  address-  job-  description-  visibility-  userid-
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    John      112     233    a@a.com    2435     dfdf 34.  test     uzlh           0            1
```

Comment: In session you have current user id .before update the card information you can check "userid" wihch is in card table  same as session "userid". if it matches update the card else redirect to back

Comment: But I don't want them to even see others page.

Comment: you can do the same thing on page load.
You get the id of card and session details of the current user. 
using card id get the details of the card and match the user id in card details to user in session

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like that

```
$getstmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id= ?");

if ($getstmt and
    $getstmt->bind_param('i', $id) and
    $getstmt->execute() and
    $result = $getstmt->get_result() and
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    ) {
     if($row['userid'] == $_SESSION['id']){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $phone2 = $row['phone2'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $zipcode = $row['zipcode'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $job = $row['job'];
        $description = $row['description'];
    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

}
```

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to match `$userid` with `$_SESSION['id']` both of these variable pointing to same value use  `$_GET['id']` instead of `$userid`

```
    if( $_SESSION['id'] !=  $_GET['id']){
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit();
     }
```

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`